# regression equation of factorial design

Tags: regression, minitab

I was wondering why I get a different kind of regression equation when I do the same data in a different way(create DOE in the minitab vs type the data myself ).

For example, when I do the job as the picture below:

[image]

I can get the regression equation.
However, If I create a new factorial design as the picture below,
I got a different equation, and I did not know how to use that equation to predict the response.
[image]
I did the setting because I would like to analyze the 3 level experiment.
I would like to know what the second equation means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted a stage from your first example. After reading the data from excel you must have used DOE -> Define Custom Factorial Design and specified that the data was "uncoded".
[image]
That caused'power' and 'time' to be treated as continuous variables which can take any real value. In terms of measurement level <[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement)> they are at least interval, if not ratio. That is to say, for exanmple, the difference between 50 and 100 is the same as that between 150 and 200. In Minitab's nomenclature <[link](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/supporting-topics/basics/what-are-categorical-discrete-and-continuous-variables/)> they are treated as continuous variables.  In the regression equation 'power' or 'time' indicate the actual values.

In the second example 'power' and 'time' are treated as factors, after all you did create a factorial design. They can take only the discrete values you indicated, not intermediate values. In terms of measurement level they are no more than ordinal, In Minitab's nomenclature they are categorical. The analysis treats the values as just 'Low' or 'High' with no regard to the values you entered, those values are just labels for the 'Low' and 'High' levels. In the regression equation `- 1.03000 power_50 + 1.03000 power_250` means: if power = 50 add -1.03 (i.e. subtract 1.03),  if power = 250 add 1.03. **NOTE: power cannot take any other values**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

However, I did not use the "Define Custom Factorial" to design the experiment.
I used the Create Factorial design--> general full factorial where I can set 3^k design in the future. I think in the general full factorial one, they did not treat the factor as continuous. Moreover, there is no option for me to choose "Uncoded" as you said.

Therefore, How do I create a 3^k design with factors treated as continuous one in general full factorial design, or is there other ways?
I would like to get the continuous regression equation with 3^k design.

Comment: 1) I'm not expert in Stack Exchange but think this is not the way to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: 2) You need more intensive help than I can give; consult a local expert.
3) Your words contradict Minitab's meanings. E.g. you say "factors treated as continuous" but Minitab says "Factors can be … based on a continuous variable but only use a few controlled values".
4) Design is not analysis. You can analyse a factorial design with regression.
5) For a 3-level design with continuous variables consider a face centred response surface design.